# GUI does not shows Nimbus when run on using Main Class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel, nimbus

Just wanna ask as I keep wondering and search for on the Mr.Google but nothing helps me.

I developed a java desktop application using Netbeans, it works fine until I try to run it.
When I run it by clicking run file on the GUI class it shows Nimbus look and feel.

But when I run through my main class ( calling the setVisible ) it shows metal look and feel.

Can I know what actually went wrong? I don't touch anything for the generated code.
Is there anybody who have the same problem and have solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the look and feel before it is visible (or else you'll be forced to update the component tree for every visible component). Before you call `setVisible(true)` on your `JFrame`, the following line should be present:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: Josh, I already try to set it like that. But still doesn't work. This only happen if I called the frame using setVisible from main. If I just run the frame,it works fine.